# ¿Cómo pasar los datos de un input text a una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Quisiera saber ¿Cómo puedo hacer para al presionar un botón se llene la fila de una tabla con los datos de los input?

Esta es la imagen, de como se ve la forma:
La idea es que al presionar el botón agregar, se coloquen lo de los input a la fila de la tabla.

Este es el código que tengo en la vista.

```
                         <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id ="pres" name="pres" placeholder="Presentación" disabled="disabled" value="@ViewBag.presentacion">
                             </div>
                         </div>

                          <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id ="cant" name="cant" placeholder="Cantidad" enabled="disabled" value="cantidad">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="col-md-5">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id ="frec" name="frec" placeholder="Frecuencia" enabled="enabled" value="frecuencia">
                             </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-md-5">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id ="dur" name="dur" placeholder="Duracion" enabled="enabled" value="duracion">
                             </div>
                         </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <div class="form-group text-right">
                                <div class="set-form">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-style-one" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();">Agregar</button>
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tablaMedicamento">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Código</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Medicamento</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Presentación </th>
                                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Frecuencia</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Duración</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                          

                        </table>
                   
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Y este es mi archivo de js, pero parece no funcionar,cada vez que le doy al botón de la página solamente me recarga el sitio, sin hacer nada.

```
<script>
    function add_fields() {
        var table = document.getElementById('tablaMedicamento');
        var codigo = document.getElementsByClassName('cod');
        var medicamento = document.getElementsByClassName('med');
        var presentacion = document.getElementsByClassName('pres');
        var cantidad = document.getElementsByClassName('cant');
        var frecuencia = document.getElementsByClassName('frec');
        var duracion = document.getElementsByClassName('dur');

        document.getElementById('tablaMedicamento').innerHTML += '<tr> <td>'+codigo +'</td> <td>'+medicamento +'</td><td>' +presentacion + '</td><td>' +cantidad+'</td><td>' +frecuencia+'</td><td>'+duracion +'</td></tr>';

</script>
```

Por favor, necesito ayudA.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tú botón es de tipo `submit` por el cual ejecuta la función y luego hace el submit del formulario. Prueba poniendo el tipo `button`.  Aparte en tu función tienes que armar el  `tr` y añadirselo al table.

Comment: Hola! Ya lo intenté de esa manera pero no me funciona...

Comment: Pon el código completo del formulario en la pregunta, faltan los inputs de med y cod. Cambia todos los getElementsByClassName por getElementById. Agrega un `.value` en cada uno de ellos dentro de la función. Cierra la función con llave `}`. Y  cuéntanos que es `enabled="disabled"` porque no me suena como atributo de nada.